# Map object key and value return undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Map that has a key object and value(always object).
I want to get the value of this map by an index object that I pass but it always return *undefined*.

It's a survey that depends on schedule id and question ids. My purpose is to get the selected answers of the schedule and questions.

I try in this way

```
export interface KeyAnswer {
   idSchedule: number;
   idQuestion: number;
}

mapSelectedAnswer: Map<KeyAnswer, Partial<Answer>> = new Map<KeyAnswer, Partial<Answer>();



this.mapSelectedAnswer.set({ idSchedule: this.schedule, idQuestion:value }, answer);



const answerSelected: Partial<Answer> = this.mapSelectedAnswer.get({ idSchedule: idSchedule, idQuestion: idQuestion});
```

But in the get I always have *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is because you are trying to use a complex object as a key. When you do that equality check done with references between two objects. And it will always log false when you try to log this in to console :

```
 { idSchedule: this.schedule, idQuestion:value } === { idSchedule: this.schedule, idQuestion:value }
```

What you can do is to preserve the key with a variable, which is not feasible at all. Or convert your key into a string and use `JSON.stringify` to create your keys like below :

```
mapSelectedAnswer: Map<string, Partial<Answer>> = new Map<string, Partial<Answer>();
this.mapSelectedAnswer.set(JSON.stringify({ idSchedule: this.schedule, idQuestion:value }), answer);


const answerSelected: Partial<Answer> = this.mapSelectedAnswer.get(JSON.stringify({ idSchedule: idSchedule, idQuestion: idQuestion}));
```

Comment: I was convinced that more complex variables could be used.. ok thank for your perfect response

Comment: @travis_91 yes but you need to keep the reference